# Decrypt error in TLS handshake after ServerKeyExchange

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have a WEB application deployed to Tomcat server. I connect to it with Chrome browser with HTTPS but I have decrypt error during TLS handshaking on the client side after ServerKeyExchange.

Certificates (3 levels):

Server certificate, signed by...

CA certificate, signed by...

Root certificate (self signed)

I validated certificates with openssl and they seem to be fine (chain.cer contains CA and root certificates):

```
$ openssl verify -verbose -CAfile chain.cer server.cer
```

server.cer: OK

If I test connection with OpenSSL I get error after client reads ServerKeyExchange:

```
openssl.exe s_client -CAfile chain.cer -showcerts -state -msg server.net:8443
```

output:

```
    CONNECTED(00000004)
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 01 01 4f
>>> TLS 1.3, Handshake [length 014f], ClientHello
    01 00 01 4b 03 03 81 63 a4 15 45 bf 7f 9b 07 8f ...
<<< ??? [length 0005]
    16 03 03 09 14
<<< TLS 1.3, Handshake [length 0055], ServerHello
    02 00 00 51 03 03 60 ef d0 8b 1c d7 9a 78 2d d4 ...
<<< TLS 1.2, Handshake [length 07ee], Certificate
    0b 00 07 ea 00 07 e7 00 07 e4 30 82 07 e0 30 82 ...
depth=2 O = Amadeus IT group SA, CN = amarootca2
verify return:1
depth=1 O = Amadeus IT group SA, CN = amacatech3
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, L = Nice, O = Amadeus Data Processing, OU = NIS, CN = nceiptapas04.nce.amadeus.net
verify return:1
<<< TLS 1.2, Handshake [length 00cd], ServerKeyExchange
    0c 00 00 c9 03 00 17 41 04 82 07 58 e1 cd 42 40 ...
>>> ??? [length 0005]
    15 03 03 00 02
>>> TLS 1.2, Alert [length 0002], fatal decrypt_error
  02 33 
  34359738384:error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length:crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c:132:
  34359738384:error:1416D07B:SSL routines:tls_process_key_exchange:bad signature:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2405:
---
```

Cannot client decrypt DH parameters sent by server? Why?
Here is Wireshark details from ServerKeyExchange:
[image]

Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 (0x0804)
Signature Length: 128

I have another but properly working WEB application where I have the same Signature Algorithm but the Signature Length: 256. Or this length is irrelevant?

Comment: This probably isn't a programming or development issue. Although the alert is coded as 'decrypt' there is actually no encryption or decryption and the problem is _signature verification_ (see `int_rsa_verify` in the first errorstack entry) (and of ECDH params not DH). Yes, the length of the signature in the SKX message must match the verifying (public) key in the _certificate_ which in turn must match the private key used by the server. The privatekey, which you don't describe, is probably what is wrong; check that.